# Help with drift wood for fish tank

Tags: aquarium

I got root wood from a long dead tree in my backyard it's been dead for about three years and the wood hasn't rotted but would it be possible for me to make it safe to put in my fish tank

Comment: Yes you can, the question Matt linked pretty much has the answer you need, just make sure the wood does not degrade during the process because then it will do so in your tank and it'll be a mess.